# Connecting a Microsoft Access Database to Java using JDBC - error

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I'm trying to get information from a MS Access database using Java.

First, I added ODBC from here

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

since I'm working on Windows 7.

and then , I used this code

```
String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
Class.forName(driver);         

String db = "jdbc:odbc:DataSource";
con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
```

But I got this error

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

after googling this error, I think the problem is that I'm working on Windows 7 64-bit and MS Office 32-bit.
The question is how can I solve this problem without having MS Office 64-bit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On the almight [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms712362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I quote:

> If you use the 64-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or remove a DSN that
>   connects to a 32-bit driver, for example, Driver do Microsoft Access
>   (*.mdb), you will receive the following error message:
>
> The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver
>   and Application
>
> To resolve this error, use the 32-bit odbcad32.exe to configure or
>   remove the DSN.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use the 32-bit viersion of odbcad32.exe? I tried to use this c:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe, but when the ODBC is opened, and when I press Add button, I get nothing in the Create New Data Source dialog. So, I can add a new drive.

Comment: As I have read, I have to use C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe because I'm working on Windows 7!

Comment: @user1178619 did you read the entire link? the **32** in `odbcad32.exe` doens't mean it is version 32-bit. You have to maybe download the 32-bit version of `odbcad32.exe` if you don't have it.